# How to completely black out background on Android dialog?

Tags: android

I am showing an Activity with dialog theme (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog")

When I pop up this activity, I want to completely blacken out the background activity. Currently, the activity underneath has too much clutter, and even though it is blurred, it is still too visible.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to setup the underneath activity background to black?

Comment: no, but that will only set its background. it has a lot of non-black buttons and ui.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=1.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 1):

make a file `style.xml` and put this xml code

```
<style name="blackDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>    
</style>
```

In your manifest file add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` attribute in your activity

```
<activity android:theme="@style/blackDialog" 
      android:name=".Activity2" 
      android:label="@string/title" />
```

Comment: this sets the dialog's background to black? i'm actually looking to black out the background activity. by default, it is blurred.

Comment: yes, i tried it and it just set the dialog activity's background to black